# how to get checked of checkbox from other class?

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences, imagebutton

I have a checkbox in Setting.class:

```
Checkbox checkBoxFlash = findViewById(R.id.checkBoxFlash);
if(checkBoxFlash.isChecked()) {
        checkBoxFlash.setChecked(mPrefe.getBoolean(KEY_CHECKED_FLASH, true));
    }else{
        checkBoxFlash.setChecked(mPrefe.getBoolean(KEY_CHECKED_FLASH, false));
    }

checkBoxFlash.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if(compoundButton.isChecked()){
                myEditor.putBoolean(KEY_CHECKED_FLASH, true);
                myEditor.apply();
            }else{
                myEditor.putBoolean(KEY_CHECKED_FLASH, false);
                myEditor.apply();
            }
        }
    });
```

and I have a ImageButton in Main.class:

```
ImageButton imgStart = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonStart);
imgStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked(); //error in here

            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.checkBoxFlash:
                    try {

                        mCameraId = mCameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (checked) {
                        turnOnFlash();
                    } else {
                        turnOffFlash();
                    }
                    break;
```

I got an error in

```
                boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
// java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
```

Why can not I declare it? and Can I know how to check it in Main.class?
My purpose is click ImageButton it will perform function of checkbox! 
Thanks for a questions! (sorry if i'm wrong english grammar)

Comment: Please mention your flow of application and give proper code of both class and also mention which class is a launcher class as well as mentioned what you want?

Comment: The error showing right because you try to cast ImageButton to CheckBox. That's why this error message showing.

Comment: The `view` in your `OnClickListener` is referring to the view `imageButtonStart`.

Answer (score 0):

boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked(); //error in here

In this line you are casting checkbox to ImageButton.

You try to get checked value from checkBoxFlash view like

boolean checked = checkBoxFlash.isChecked();